# Why BeautifulSoup can't find this supposed-to-be xbrl related "ix" tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It turns out that the tag name should be: "ix:nonfraction"

This does not work. No "xi" tag is found.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<td style="BORDER-BOTTOM:0.75pt solid #7f7f7f;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">$ <ix:nonfraction name="ecd:AveragePrice" contextref="P01_01_2022To12_31_2022" unitref="Unit_USD" decimals="2" scale="0" format="ixt:num-dot-decimal">97.88</ix:nonfraction>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
ix_tags = soup.find_all('ix')
print(ix_tags)
```

But the following works. I don't see a difference. Why is it? Thanks a lot!

```
html_content = """
<html>
  <body>
    <ix>Tag 1</ix>
    <ix>Tag 2</ix>
    <ix>Tag 3</ix>
    <p>Not an ix tag</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
ix_tags = soup.find_all('ix')
for tag in ix_tags:
    print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Use " "ix:nonfraction"" as the tag name and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here arises from how BeautifulSoup handles namespaced tags like `<ix:nonfraction>`. With the `lxml` parser, namespaced tags might not be correctly parsed or recognized.

In the XML you provided, `ix` is the namespace, and `nonfraction` is the local name of the element. In XML, a namespace is a method to avoid name conflicts by differentiating elements or attributes within XML documents. The `ix:nonfraction` tag indicates that the `nonfraction` element is part of the `ix` namespace.

To correctly find namespaced tags like `<ix:nonfraction>` when using the `lxml` parser, you should use the exact tag name in your `find_all` call:

```py
ix_tags = soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction')
```

If you want to find the tags without providing the namespace, then you can use the `xml` parser which handles namespaced tags much more gracefully.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')
ix_tags = soup.find_all('nonfraction')
```

Sample run:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<td style="BORDER-BOTTOM:0.75pt solid #7f7f7f;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right;">$ <ix:nonfraction name="ecd:AveragePrice" contextref="P01_01_2022To12_31_2022" unitref="Unit_USD" decimals="2" scale="0" format="ixt:num-dot-decimal">97.88</ix:nonfraction>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
ix_tags = soup.find_all('ix:nonfraction')
print(ix_tags)


soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')
ix_tags = soup.find_all('nonfraction')
print(ix_tags)
```

Output:

```
[<ix:nonfraction contextref="P01_01_2022To12_31_2022" decimals="2" format="ixt:num-dot-decimal" name="ecd:AveragePrice" scale="0" unitref="Unit_USD">97.88</ix:nonfraction>]
[<nonfraction contextref="P01_01_2022To12_31_2022" decimals="2" format="ixt:num-dot-decimal" name="ecd:AveragePrice" scale="0" unitref="Unit_USD">97.88</nonfraction>]
```

Answer (score 1):

`ix:nonfraction` is an XML name denoting `nonfraction` in the namespace specified by an `xmlns:ix` attribute.

In the absence of that namespace declaration attribute, I'd probably try without the namespace, ie. look for `nonfraction` instead, or alternatively the entire `ix:nonfraction` name.